# Chartjs y axis getting cut off with long numbers

Tags: charts

On Line and Vertical Bar charts on Chart.js, sometimes the values on the y-axis get cut off when the numbers are to long. See image below. I have only noticed this issue on these two graph types.

[Image of y axis being cut off](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i0fGJ.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can fix that by setting the layout padding on the chart.

```
options: {
  layout: {
    padding: {
      left: 10
    }
  }
}
```

Reference: http://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/configuration/layout.html